# Dubious permissions on plist Problems installing Jenkins

Tags: macos, mac, permissions, plist

I am trying to install jenkins on 10.6.8.

In order to do this, I needed to modify the jenkins plist which was owned by root.  I gave myself (the admin) permissions to modify this file and added the admin as the user in the plist for jenkins.

Now, the problem is that `launchctrl` sees my permission change as a security issue and will not launch -- something about dubious permissions on plist.

I changed owner to root, and removed admin permission to write but `launchctrl` still views the permissions as dubious?

Time for a reinstall?  How should I have set the plist in the first place? and what should I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the file is owned by root but writable by non-root, you'll get the dubious ownership warning. Change the ownership back to root and the permissions to root-only.
See also: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3250/why-am-i-getting-a-dubious-ownership-of-file-error-when-launch-agent-runs-my